# How can I get Google Navigation (navigation in Maps) on Android to navigate walking directions?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-navigation, gps-tracking

I know how to get walking/public transportation/biking *directions*, but driving directions are the only ones I can navigate (tracks the location, shows turns coming up, compensates for wrong turns, etc.).  How can I navigate on the walking directions?

And yeah, I know that I can show the walking directions on the map, and try to follow them myself, but then it's always north up instead of track up and it doesn't make any attempts to snap the GPS location to the street.

Comment: I've looked for this myself — I don't think it's possible. A similar missing feature is that on the Google Maps web site, you can't save a bicycle route to My Maps. I think the non-car navigation is just generally not-fully-integrated.

Comment: @Kevin That's what I was afraid of.  It's too bad.  The two different services both function really well.  I wish they worked together just as well.

Answer (score 10):

Walking Navigation was [just released today [Sept 9]](http://www.engadget.com/2010/09/09/google-walking-navigation-beta-and-street-view-now-available-for/) as an update to [Google Maps 4.5.0](http://www.cyrket.com/p/android/com.google.android.apps.maps/)

Comment: Here's the official Google announcement: http://googlemobile.blogspot.com/2010/09/walk-this-way.html

Comment: Sweet, thanks for letting me know!  Used it a couple times today; it works great!